# There is any way to add classes to bootstrap_django form_fields?

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, class, django-templates

https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3
I like it very much.

By the way I'll need to add classes to customize my ui and add behaviors class based.
I'll like to do it template side.

I use that:

{% bootstrap_form form_field FIXTHIS %}

but I can't understand if:
- the project it's too young, haven't that feature
- the feature is usable, I'm not able
- general skill problem of mine on Django: wrong approach to the problem

Here the docs:
http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-field

EDIT:
that do the trick, still using django_bootstrap.
By the way is in the form.py file.
Is that approach right or I should keep trying to move that logic in the template?

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['code','name','birthdate',]
        widgets = {
            'birthdate': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
        }
```

Comment: Django's policy is that: less logic in template. So I will suggest that you should keep logic in forms or use template-tags

Comment: You might take a look at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks

Comment: Thank you @Brandon, I took a look. the project last commit is on 2013-04-04 ... Now I'm oriented on WTForm... :) Not so bad. http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: You're welcome. I still find Django Widget Tweaks immensely useful, even though it hasn't had any new development in a while. I wouldn't let that discourage you from using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the classes in the form, like the following:

'email': TextInput(attrs={**'class': 'form-control'**, 'placeholder': ('Type your email here')}),

Comment: so you confirm it's not possible atm to do it template side.

Comment: I am not sure, but it's better to do it from form side.